# How to detect multiple gestures using a single instance of GestureDetector?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, gesturedetector

I want make WhatsApp voice audio record function. User tap and hold to record audio but can swipe left to cancel. But when I use GestureDetector it only register one gesture type.

For example this only register onLongPress gesture if user start with long press. Or only onHorizontalDrag if user start with horizontal drag:

```
          onLongPressStart: _onPressStart,
          onLongPressUp: _onPressEnd,
          onHorizontalDragDown: _onHorizontalDragDown,
          onHorizontalDragUpdate: _onHorizontalDragUpdate,
          onHorizontalDragEnd: _onHorizontalDragEnd,
```

How to use 2 gesture one after the other?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using `onLongPressMoveUpdate` callback provided by `GestureDetector`

This provides `LongPressMoveUpdateDetails` which has a property called `offsetFromOrigin`.

`offsetFromOrigin` gives you an `Offset` object whose `dx` value is what you need.

```dart
GestureDetector(
  child: ...
  onLongPressMoveUpdate: (updateDetails) { 
      if (updateDetails.offsetFromOrigin.dx < 0) {
          // Handle horizontal drag towards left
      }
  }
)
```

Or, if you can't use the above method, checkout this [Medium article](https://medium.com/koahealth/combining-multiple-gesturedetectors-in-flutter-26d899d008b2)

Comment: Thanks for reply! But this too sensitive. I need user drag 50 pixel before I want trigger callback

Comment: @FlutterFirebase, you can simply update the min value with which you are comparing

Comment: For example, you could change it to be less than -10 or -20